# Month field is not getting drill down in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am calculating total revenue over the years.
There are two tables calendar and sales. I have calculated total revenue using DAX now I want to display total revenue in each year.

The month field is not getting filtered for the Revenue column, I have attached a snip for reference.

```
Total revenue(DAX)= total revenue = SUMX(AW_Sales,AW_Sales[OrderQuantity] * RELATED(AW_Products_Lookup[ProductPrice]))
```

[image]